# How to divides two columns in the same line on listview using xamarin c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I have a simple `ListView` filled with data from database. When I display the data I want to display with two columns but Values are still arranged one below the other.

[Grid Exactly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEYDE.png)

The xaml code look like this:

```
           <StackLayout>
              <ListView x:Name="MeteoView"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Forecast}"
                        HeightRequest="200"
                        IsVisible="false">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                  <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label  Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding DisplayDat}"/>
                        <Label  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DisplayT_2M}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
                  </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
```

How to arrange with two columns on one line ?

Comment: Your layout looks correct, I suspect there is something wrong with your data.  Try hardcoding test values in your Labels to verify that it's a data issue and not a Layout issue.

Comment: MeteoData.Add(new ForecastData { DisplayDat = reader[1].ToString()  });

Comment: MeteoData.Add(new ForecastData { DisplayT_2M = reader[3].ToString() + " °C" });

Comment: you are adding one row with one property, and then adding another row with the other property.

Comment: `MeteoData.Add(new ForecastData { DisplayDat = reader[1].ToString(), DisplayT_2M = reader[3].ToString() + " °C" });`

Comment: I not want to post another noob question, how can I set column names above first and second column ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#headers-and-footers

Answer (score 0):

Your item layout is correct, most likely some of your data entries have only the date, while others have only the temperature. On your screenshot, you have 5 separate data entries, each is rendered correctly (date - temp in one line).

I would recommend starting without data binding if you want to verify the layout and some optimizations to your layout:

1. Keep it flat (no outer `StackLayout` is required for `ListView`)
2. If you have just one row, you can skip adding definition, it will be inferred
3. If you have all columns the same equal width, you can skip definition and just apply `Grid.Column` attribute
4. Switch from `ListView` to `CollectionView`

```
<ListView x:Name="MeteoView"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Forecast}"
                        HeightRequest="200"
                        IsVisible="false">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <Grid>
          <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Date"/>
          <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Temperature"/>
        </Grid>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```